# Reverse a string in c++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, reverse

I have just started coding in c++.

I wrote a code for reverse a string . I get null results.

```
void main ()
{
    string str1="abcde";string rev="";
    int n=str1.size();
    for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        rev += str1[i];
    }
printf("%s \n", rev);
}
```

Could anyone please tell me.

Comment: `%s` means "c-style null-terminated string", which `std::string` is not. If you are starting in C++ you might want to forget about the C functions such as `printf` completely.

Comment: Use `cout<<` to print a `std::string`. Or `printf` the _contents_ of the string instead of the string itself. The contents can be retrieved by calling `c_str()` on the string object.

Comment: `main` must return an `int`

Comment: `std::reverse(str1.begin(), str1.end());`

Comment: @NeilKirk indeed, but the only difference is that the OP doesn't modify the original string in place, so strictly speaking it's not equivalent

Answer (score 5):

`std::string` is being printed with `%s` format specifier. Try to change

```
printf("%s \n", rev);
```

with

```
printf("%s \n", rev.c_str());
```

Or as @Appleshell suggested, make it in `C++` style:

```
std::cout << rev << "\n";
```

---

**PS**

Clearly, there are out-of-the-box ways to reverse strings, but I assume the idea was to have complete implementation.

Comment: Or to [`cout << rev << "\n";`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout)

Answer (score 4):

First of all function main in C++ and in C shall have return type `int`. So it shall be defined as

```
int main()
{
   //...
```

Secondly the member function `size()` has an unsigned integral return type. So it would be better to write

```
std::string::size_type n = str1.size();
```

Thirdly you should use C++ streams instead of C streams in a C++ program. C function printf is unable to output objects of type std::string. So you have to pass on a pointer to character array that is returned by member function `c_str()`

The loop could be written the following way

```
std::string::size_type n = str1.size();

for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
   rev[i] = str1[n - i - 1];
}
```

Take into account that you could get the reversed string simpler. For example

```
std::string rev( str1.rbegin(), str1.rend() );
```

without using any loop.

So the program could look as

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
    std::string str1 = "abcde";
    std:: string rev( str1.rbegin(), str1.rend() );

    std::cout << str1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << rev << std::endl;

    std::string::size_type n = rev.size();

    for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        // std::swap( rev[i], rev[n - i - 1] );
        char c = rev[i];
        rev[i] = rev[n - i - 1];
        rev[n - i - 1] = c;
    }

    std::cout << str1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << rev << std::endl;
}
```